# python with lightgbm, predict the class label (0 or 1) rather than the probability

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm

I am using lightgbm. I want to know how to get the class label (0 or 1) not the probability for classification.

I know that lightgbm has provided scikit-learn API. The API has the function "predict" to get label and "predict_proba" to the probability. I want to get the label directly without scikit-learn API.

The question is similar with how to get the label based on the probability. We can use the threshold. Probabilities exceeding the threshold are set to one, and probabilities which are less than the threshold are set to zero. Obviously, the threshold 0.5 is not appropriate.

I use following codes to find the best threshold, but there must be something wrong:

```
def find_optimal_cutoff(target, predicted):

    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(target, predicted)
    i = np.arange(len(tpr))
    roc = pd.DataFrame({'tf': pd.Series(tpr - (1 - fpr), index=i), 'threshold': pd.Series(threshold, index=i)})
    roc_t = roc.loc[(roc.tf - 0).abs().argsort()[:1]]
    return list(roc_t['threshold'])[0]


def find_optimal_cutoff2(target, predicted):

    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(target, predicted)
    optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
    optimal_threshold = threshold[optimal_idx]
    return optimal_threshold

thre1 = find_optimal_cutoff(self, target, predicted) 

thre2 = find_optimal_cutoff2(self, target, predicted)
```

`thre1` is a little different from `thre2`. But this is not the core problem. If the parameters for the lightgbm model are not appropriate, my experiment shows that the auc is approximately 0.5. However, `thre1` is 1 and `thre2` is 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
    np.where(predictions_lgbm_prob > 0.5, 1, 0)